# Inserir mais de uma linha em um gráfico no R

Tags: r

Bom dia,

Estou tentando inserir três linhas horizontais no meu gráfico, mas quando utilizo a função abline, insere somente uma. Além disso, estou com dificuldade de inserir a linha vertical, uma vez que meu eixo x é no formato de data, e não estou conseguindo setar o parâmetro para que a linha apareça, e o mesmo erro acontece para definir o limite do eixo x, também preciso ajustar isso.

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado!

```
plot(base$data, base$km_media_dia, 
ylim = c(0,10000),
main = "Distribuição da Kilometragem Média no ano de 2018",
xlab = "Data da Revisão",
ylab = "KM Média por Dia",
col = "blue", # define a cor dos pontos
pch = 1, # o formato dos pontos
bg = "blue", # cor de preenchimento
tcl = 0.4, # tamanho dos traços dos eixos
las = 1, # orientação do texto em y
cex = 0.5, # tamanho do objeto do ponto
bty = "l", # altera as bordas
abline(h = 150, col = "green", lwd = 2), #insere a linha horizontal)
abline(h = 1000, col = "red", lwd = 2)) #insere a linha horizontal)


structure(list(cpf = c("74272004620", "29563619889", "3822693650", 
"35204060634", "35204060634", "11116607603", "38035027808", "27758635822", 
"5188980754", "1789879051"), placa = c("OWU-5046", "EPX-1756", 
"PWB-9077", "HNB-3723", "HNB-3723", "BIH-9437", "FVV-8511", "FTN-4023", 
"KZL-7188", "IPV-6361"), revisao = c(714003L, 714002L, 714001L, 
714000L, 713999L, 713998L, 713997L, 713996L, 713995L, 713994L
), data = c("2018-07-04 16:16:30.163", "2018-07-04 16:16:10.443", 
"2018-07-04 16:16:04.037", "2018-07-04 16:15:40.663", "2018-07-04 16:15:40.117", 
"2018-07-04 16:15:33.833", "2018-07-04 16:15:00.000", "2018-07-04 16:14:59.317", 
"2018-07-04 16:14:45.647", "2018-07-04 16:14:37.000"), km_atual = c("57090", 
"286725", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "175767", "53461", "42244", 
"46062", "102432"), km_media = c("5", "137", "25", "100", "100", 
"15", "40", "40", "20", "10"), X7 = c("dia", "dia", "dia", "men", 
"men", "dia", "dia", "dia", "dia", "dia"), km_media_dia = c("5", 
"137", "25", "3,333333333", "3,333333333", "15", "40", "40", 
"20", "10"), est_dir = c("cdd", "cdd", "cdd", "cdd", "cdd", "cdd", 
"cdd", "cdd", "cdd", "cdd"), cambio = c("mnl", "mnl", "mnl", 
"mnl", "mnl", "mnl", "atc", "mnl", "mnl", "mnl"), loja = c(187L, 
98L, 110L, 230L, 230L, 209L, 122L, 120L, 90L, 72L), smart = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("cpf", "placa", 
"revisao", "data", "km_atual", "km_media", "X7", "km_media_dia", 
"est_dir", "cambio", "loja", "smart"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: As chamadas a `abline` não podem estar dentro do `plot()`. Basta fechar o parêntesis imediatamente a seguir a `bty = "l")` e tirar o `)` a mais a seguir ao segundo `abline`. Nota: tal como os dados estão, o `plot` não reconhece a coluna `data` como sendo uma data, é necessário `base$data <- as.POSIXct(etc)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta formatar sua série como xts:

```
base$km_media_dia=as.numeric(base$km_media_dia)
#options(digits.secs=3)
base$data=as.POSIXct(base$data, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") #format.Date(base$data)
plot(xts::xts(base$km_media_dia, base$data), 
     ylim = c(0,2000),
     main = "Distribuição da Kilometragem Média no ano de 2018",
     xlab = "Data da Revisão",
     ylab = "KM Média por Dia",
     col = "blue", # define a cor dos pontos
     pch = 1, # o formato dos pontos
     bg = "lightblue", # cor de preenchimento
     tcl = 0.4, # tamanho dos traços dos eixos
     las = 1, # orientação do texto em y
     cex = 0.5, # tamanho do objeto do ponto
     bty = "l" # altera as bordas
)
     abline(h = 150, col = "green", lwd = 2) #insere a linha horizontal)
     abline(h = 1000, col = "red", lwd = 2) #insere a linha horizontal)
abline(v=as.POSIXct("2018-07-04 16:14:49.663", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"),col=6)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]